# How to create vbox file for virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, uuid, snapshot, vmdk

**Situation**:
I had centos before and everythung was working. Now when i got debian on my system, virtualbox dont let me add the existing vmdk and show me errors about mismatched UUIDs of vmdk to its snapshots. The errors are shown when virtualbox try to load the .vbox file of my VM.

**To avoid errors**:
I ignored the snapshots and copied the vmdk in new folder, changed its UUID, created new VM and attached the vmdk. Everythung is ok except for

**One big problem**:
The VM when start i see old data. That means the missing old snapshot if not attached to the new VM then latest data is not recovered. And to attach the snapshot i have to change the .vbox file and i dont know any easy way to do that.

**Questions**:

**1**. Is there any tool or help on how to create the .vbox file from
    scratch?

**2**. In that perticular situation what is the best way to get my latest
    data from vmdk+snapshots?

Comment: Can you please post the `vbox` file? I looked up one of my own and I can see the following: `<Machine uuid="{351857d7-3f88-4004-ab80-fbf48a5ae201}" name="lubros" OSType="Ubuntu" stateFile="Snapshots/2016-03-24T18-12-27-607647000Z.sav" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2016-03-24T18:12:34Z">` You can see that there are multiple snapshot-related parameters namely the `sav` file (where the snapshot is stored), the snapshot folder and a timestamp where the VM was last changed.

Comment: [in the .vbox file](http://pastebin.com/Ts36nmZt) there are 5 snapshots for the main vmdk file. And for testing you had better attach just one with its vmdk in the vbox file. Just my guess, if one is attached successfully then others will be attached on the same track. thank you for taking interest in it. And also if you create vmdk and its snapshots on your system then it will be easier for you to change the UUIDs of the both (the vmdk and its snapshot which is a vmdk too) for testing. Main purpose as you know is to find out the way how we can edit or create a .vbox file.

Comment: Actually, problem started when UUID of the main vmdk was changed and .vbox file did not reflect the change because as you know thers is not any GUI option in virtualbox to change the UUID. In other words virtualbox does not take any responsibility to repflect the change done in terminal/prompt. So that is the purpose and real work, "we change UUIDs of both the main vmd and all its snapshots, new UUIDs are added in the .vbox file and obsolete UUIDs are removed. In the last step we use virtualbox GUI to add existing vmdk"

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the documentation for a tool to automate the process. Btw your question would likely find a higher chance of a response on [superuser](http://www.superuser.com) then here since it's not related to programming at all. I will flag it to be moved there.

Comment: Thank you @rbeleksandar. I did try to make new .vbox but found two more UUIDs ( in the .vbox file) that are not related to any .vmdk files (neither main vmdk nor its snapshot vmdk) that are for Machine and Snapshot. And i dont know how to get/set UUIDs for any files that dont exist under the main folder. I am not sure what to do next except for waiting answer.